# Keras model in R problem with image_array

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, tiff

I am trying to write a Keras model in R, but I am encountering some problems.
I have a list of multipage TIFF files (they are obtained from an instrument, and each page is a different color of the same object), so my first idea was to stack them in a single jpeg image.
The stacking is successful, but the main problem comes when I try to convert the image to a format that is compatible with the Keras model.
To the best of my understanding, I should convert each image to an array.
For this purpose, I use "image_array".
But it fails, and it gives me this error:

```
Error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PyCapsule'
```

I have put also the rest of my code with the model, but currently, I wanted to use it only to see if I am able to run it. In fact, the labels are assigned randomly, there is no training set or test set.  I just want to put the code in place to read the images and feed them to the model.
Any help?

```
library(keras)
library(magick)
library(tensorflow)




# define the directory of the tiff files
adir="../qptiff/"
# list the files with a given pattern in it
lfiles=list.files(path = adir, pattern ="resolution", recursive = TRUE )

# obtain an ID from the name of the file
get_id=function(x){
  x=strsplit(x, "/")[[1]][4]
  return(strsplit(x, "_Scan")[[1]][1])
  
}

# create a dataframe with the location of the image and its ID
adf=data.frame(file=paste0(adir,lfiles), id=sapply(lfiles, get_id))

## store the images as array in data
data=list()
for(i in 1:nrow(adf)){
  image <- image_read(adf$file[i])
  image <- image_append(image, stack=TRUE)
  image <- image_convert(image, "jpg")
  image <- image_scale(image, "2000x2000")
  image_array <- image_to_array(image) / 255 # Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
  data[[i]] <- array_reshape(image_array, c(2000, 2000, 1))
}

### assign random labels just to have something to feed to the keras model
labels=sample(1:2, length(data), replace=TRUE)


# Define the model architecture
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu", input_shape = c(2000, 2000, 1)) %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 64, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 128, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>%
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

# Compile the model
model %>% compile(
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr = 1e-4),
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)

# Train the model
history <- model %>% fit(
  data, labels,
  epochs = 10,
  batch_size = 1,
  validation_split = 0.2
)
```